# trying to show re render the page when i click on the show details button

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Hello guys i am new to this i am trying to re render my page any time i click on the show details buttons so i can show the name, height and gender of the sky wars characters i have tried initializing a variable to false and on click i tried changing the value to true but it did not work. please here is my code.

```
const containerEl = document.getElementById("container");
const list = document.createDocumentFragment();
const images = [
    "https://oyster.ignimgs.com/mediawiki/apis.ign.com/star-wars-episode-7/2/2d/Luke.jpg?width=1280",
    "https://images.immediate.co.uk/production/volatile/sites/3/2019/10/EP9-FF-001686-336e75b.jpg?quality=90&resize=980,654",
    "https://hips.hearstapps.com/digitalspyuk.cdnds.net/17/07/1487160686-r2-d2.jpg",
    "https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/darth-vader-main_4560aff7.jpeg?region=0%2C67%2C1280%2C720",
    "https://www.costumerealm.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/51G4Jox9MlL._SX466_.jpg",
    "https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/e/eb/OwenCardTrader.png/revision/latest?cb=20171108050140",
    "https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/fanmade-works/images/8/8d/Beru_Lars.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width/360?cb=20200317025929",
    "https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/star-wars-canon-extended/images/2/23/R5.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20160123232521",
    "https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/0/00/BiggsHS-ANH.png/revision/latest?cb=20130305010406",
    "https://media.gq.com/photos/622919842677fb88bf480855/16:9/w_2143,h_1205,c_limit/Screen%20Shot%202022-03-09%20at%204.15.50%20PM.png"
]

const getData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/people");
    const resData = await res.json();
    const result = resData.results;
    console.log(result)
    main(result)
}

getData();

const main = (data) => {
    let isVisible = false;
    containerEl.innerHTML = "";
    data.map(({ gender, height, name }, i) => {
        const starWars = `
          <img class="images" src=${images[i]}/>
          <button id="btn" class="btn">Show Details</button>
          <h1 class="starwars">${isVisible ? name : ""}</h1>
          <h3>${isVisible ? gender : ""}</h3>
          <h3>${isVisible ? height : ""}</h3>
        `;
        const item = document.createElement("div");
        item.classList.add("items")
        item.innerHTML = starWars
        const btn = item.querySelector(".btn");
        btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
            isVisible = true
        })
        list.appendChild(item)
    })
    containerEl.append(list)
}



html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/index.css" >
    <title>Star Wars</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Write your implementation here -->
    <div id="container" class="container">
    </div>
    <script src="./script/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach is not possible.  The string literals, such as `${isVisible ? name : ""}` are evaluated at the time that your template item is created, so since you've set the `isVisible` is false, it will only ever produce an empty string.

Instead, generate your string template with the values and then use a class to toggle the visibility of the details.

```js
const containerEl = document.getElementById("container");
const images = [
    "https://oyster.ignimgs.com/mediawiki/apis.ign.com/star-wars-episode-7/2/2d/Luke.jpg?width=1280",
    "https://images.immediate.co.uk/production/volatile/sites/3/2019/10/EP9-FF-001686-336e75b.jpg?quality=90&resize=980,654",
    "https://hips.hearstapps.com/digitalspyuk.cdnds.net/17/07/1487160686-r2-d2.jpg",
    "https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/darth-vader-main_4560aff7.jpeg?region=0%2C67%2C1280%2C720",
    "https://www.costumerealm.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/51G4Jox9MlL._SX466_.jpg",
    "https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/e/eb/OwenCardTrader.png/revision/latest?cb=20171108050140",
    "https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/fanmade-works/images/8/8d/Beru_Lars.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width/360?cb=20200317025929",
    "https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/star-wars-canon-extended/images/2/23/R5.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20160123232521",
    "https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/0/00/BiggsHS-ANH.png/revision/latest?cb=20130305010406",
    "https://media.gq.com/photos/622919842677fb88bf480855/16:9/w_2143,h_1205,c_limit/Screen%20Shot%202022-03-09%20at%204.15.50%20PM.png"
]

async function getData () {
  const res = await fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/people");
  const resData = await res.json();
  return resData.results;
}

async function main () {
  const data = await getData();
  containerEl.innerHTML = "";
  const list = document.createElement("ul")
  
  data.map(({ gender, height, name }, i) => {
    const starWars = `
      <img class="images" src=${images[i]}/>
      <button id="btn" class="btn">Show Details</button>
      <div class="details">
        <h2 class="starwars">${name}</h2>
        <h3>${gender}</h3>
        <h3>${height}</h3>
      </div>
    `;
    const item = document.createElement("li");
    item.classList.add("item", "hidden")
    item.innerHTML = starWars
    const btn = item.querySelector(".btn");
    btn.addEventListener("click", toggleVisibility)
    list.appendChild(item)
  })
  containerEl.append(list)
}

main()

function toggleVisibility(event) {
  const el = event.target.closest('.item')
  el.classList.toggle("hidden")
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
}

li {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button {
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #222;
  padding: .5rem .75rem;
  color: white;
}

.item {
  display: grid;
  width: 25rem;
  margin: auto;
}

.details {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.hidden .details {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container"></div>
```